# Display a loop of card of chat list using vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i am doing a chatbox... I need to display array of chat convestation .. i could retrieve the data , and the card is looping , but i need to out in a row and display it chat title .. can anyone help me with it .

my converstation component

```
<template>
    <div class="row w-100">
        <div class="card" v-for="conversation in conversations" :key="i">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card name </h5>
                <p class="card-text">Last Chat </p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['conversation_index_route'],
    data() {
        return {
            conversations: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getConversations();
    },
    methods: {
        getConversations: function() {
            let self = this;
            axios.get(this.conversation_index_route)
                .then(response => {
                    self.conversations = response.data.data;
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

this a the conversation objects

```
0:Object
centre_id:5
children:"3828,4197,7748,11591,12376,12394,12433,12441,12754,12755,12765,13284,14149,14602,14656,14941"
classes:"139"
cover_image:"https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"
created_at:"2020-06-09 19:14:20"
exited_users:null
id:258
latest:Object
latest_chat_id:1921
parent_users:"2413,3461,11690,11770,11786,12262,12263,13077,14232,15275,16713"
staff_users:"321,16707,12117,13488,14083"
status_id:1
title:"Class 0906"
unread:0
updated_at:"2020-06-09 19:14:20"
```

Comment: Are you struggling with adding the `title` or having it display in a row?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop on conversation array add this into your inner elements.

```
<div class="card" v-for="conversation in conversations" :key="i">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"> {{ conversation.title }} </h5>
    <p class="card-text"> {{ conversation.latest }} </p>
    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"> {{ conversation.updated_at || computeAgo }} </small></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that above `updated_at` function doesn't do what have to do. You should create a filter like `computeAgo` for it then use `Date()` to compute exactly how many minutes ago.